# Insert new cell containing an empty string for rows of a list where an existing cell is None

Tags: python, list, dataframe, iterator

I have a list of data. Imagine there are 7 columns in each row.

```
    list_of_data = [
      [['Joe', 4, 4, 4, 5, 'cabbage', None], 
       ['Joe', 43, 42, 41, 53, 'cabbage', None],
       ['Joe', 24, 34, 44, 55, 'cabbage', None]],

      [['Tom', 7, 34, 4, 52, 'cabbage', None],
       ['Tom', 4, 24, 43, 52, 'cabbage', None],
       ['Tom', 4, 4, 4, 5, 'cabbage', None]],

      [['Fred', 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 'cabbage'],
       ['Fred', 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 'cabbage'],
       ['Fred', 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 'cabbage']]
    ]
```

Notice that for the rows for Joe and Tom, the last index/column contains None, but the second to last index/column contains cabbage. For the rows for Fred, the last index/column contains 'cabbage'.

I produced this list from a function that iterates through table data contained within numerous URLs. The problem is that Fred's table has an extra column at index #3, whereas the input table for Joe and Tom is missing this column at index #3. So when it produces the data, Joe's and Tom's rows starting with index #3 are filled with values that should be moved over to the right by 1 column, with a missing value at index #3.

So, for those rows where the last index/column is None, I would like to end up with an empty string at index #3 for these rows.

Or, conversely, for those rows where the last index/column is None, starting with index #3 I would like to move all columns one column to the right.

Comment: Please provide example of input and desired output. You can use lower indices like 3, 4 or something similar for this example.

Comment: @zipa I updated my question. Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. However, I don't think it is possible in pandas dataframe to insert only one cell in certain rows, instead you have to add one column.

Comment: @iparjono I just updated my question to hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: @ThomasErnste, it seems that you should modify your data parser and just generate clear data lists from your irregular input. Actually, you have here 8 columns, not 7. 2 main options here: make your input data more clear via some pre-processing or add and some extra logic which will analyze data types and generate uniform data rows.

Comment: @AliakseiRamanau I agree it would be preferable to modify my data parser. But doing that seemed much more difficult to figure out, so for the time being this fix I'm requesting help on seemed like the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in list_of_data:
    for j in i:
        if j[len(j)-1] == None:
            j.insert(3, "empty")
```